# Properties of functions with $0$ second partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, functions, polynomials, partial-derivative, harmonic-functions

I have a $n$-dimensional polynomial that I am evaluating on some domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}$
$$
f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}
$$

where I know that all the second partials are zero
$$
\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_k^2} \equiv0
$$

however, the mixed partials may be non-zero.

It is easy to see that this function is harmonic as $\nabla^2f = 0$. From this we get lots of results, such as the minima $m$ and maxima $M$ is on the boundary: $m,M\in \partial\Omega$.

This condition that all second derivatives seems stronger than being harmonic though, so I was wondering if there was a name / other properties relating to functions like this.

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps $f$ is a polynomial, of degree $\;\le 1$ in each variable.  For example, when $n=2$, $f(x,y) = a + bx + cy + dxy$.

Comment: That is the form of solutions I found for higher dimensions too, but I was wondering if that type of polynomial had a special name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These polynomials are called [multilinear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_polynomial). They are sometimes called polynomials of max degree $1$ (as opposed to total degree $1,$ which would mean affine.)

They come up naturally in Fourier analysis on $\{-1,1\}^n$: the Fourier transform passes between the representation of a multilinear polynomial by its values on $\{-1,1\}^n$ and the values of its coefficients.

They also come up in things like the polynomial method, Schwartz-Zippel lemma, and related results. The important property here is that if a multilinear polynomial $p$ is zero on a grid of the form $\{a_1,b_1\}\times\dots\times\{a_n,b_n\}$ with $a_i\neq b_i$ for each $i,$ then $p$ is identically zero.

Since you have an algebraic property of polynomials, the restriction to $\Omega$ is irrelevant. But it is true that any [distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)) on a domain $\Omega$ satisfying $\partial^2 f/\partial x_k^2=0$ must be a multilinear polynomial.

Another property, perhaps only interesting to me: they are "[nonzero at one of their multi-indices](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082561/does-every-nonzero-polynomial-take-a-nonzero-value-at-one-of-its-multi-indices)". By this I mean that if $p$ is a non-zero multilinear polynomial, there exist $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in\{0,1\}$ such that $p(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)\neq 0$ and the $x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ coefficient of $p$ is non-zero. Specifically, we can take $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$ to be minimal in the product order on $\{0,1\}^n,$ such that the coefficient $c$ of $x_1^{\alpha_1}\dots x_n^{\alpha_n}$ is non-zero. This gives $p(x_1^{\alpha_1},\dots,x_n^{\alpha_n})=c.$